# Eclipse dark theme's text color is same as background in tree view and button

Tags: eclipse, themes

[image]

As you can see, these two problem cause text unreadable completely,how to solve them?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a dark theme [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496585#c36), [issue2](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/issues/98#issuecomment-320510892) related to git that might have been resolved in eclipse 4.16.

The colour comes from the git sections since the projects are marked according to their git state …

But you can fix it manually by changing the diff colour setting:

`Window → Preferences → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Uncommitted Change (Foreground)`

**Alternatively** you can disable the git decoration:

`Preferences → General → Appearance → Label decorations` disable `Git Resources` and `Git Repository Objects`